# Calculating and visualising the future value of 100USD invested in fixed income securities and bonds in R

Tags: programming, time-series

I have uploaded TB3MS to R and would like to visualise the future value if i invest 100USD in it. The interval is from 2014 to 2019, monthly frequency.

I would like it to be comparable to a plot i have made of some stocks, which looks like this:[image]

Someone who can help with this? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be strictly about plotting in R, not quant-finance.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way. Invest 100 and carry over time assuming you get interest every month.

```
require(xts)
TB3MS = xts(TB3MS$TB3MS,order.by =as.Date(TB3MS$DATE) )
TB3MS = TB3MS['2014::']
TB3MS100 = 100
for (i in 2:length(TB3MS))TB3MS100[i] <- TB3MS100[i-1]*(1+TB3MS[i]/100)
TB3MS100 = as.xts(TB3MS100, order.by=index(TB3MS))
plot(TB3MS100,ylim=c(20,180),col=4)
```

[image]